# I added inline style to Wordpress child theme files. They're rendering on the page, but not in the theme files

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I stupidly added some inline style to my theme files with the intention of moving them to the stylesheet using classes. That was before the holiday. The styles are rendering on the page, but I have scoured every file in my parent and child theme and these inline styles do not exist. It's almost like they're permanent. Please help.

http://cannabisediblesanddrinkreview.com/

`<div class="site-branding" style="margin-bottom: 73px;">`

http://cannabisediblesanddrinkreview.com/contact

`<div class="custom-header" style="margin-bottom: 73px;">`

Comment: The inline style should be in the template-parts/site-branding.php or the header.php file. It's not!

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript file named `global.js` in "twentyseven-child/assets/js" which contains a function named "adjustHeaderHeight()". In there the `margin-bottom` of those two elements is set to `navigationOuterHeight` (a variable defined in the same file, further up). Most likely that function is adding those `style` attributes

Comment: It's not, that's what's so crazy. I remember putting it there, now it's just not.

Comment: or it could be in the "Theme Customizer"'s CSS section

Comment: Another thought: You are writing about a child theme. Check `header.php` both in the child theme folder and in the parent theme

Comment: I checked the parent files. I searched all the files. I'm going nuts here.

Comment: Please note my completely changed answer

Comment: Yeah, I checked the Theme Customizer CSS section. It's completely empty.

Comment: I meant I changed the answer itself, not the comments

Comment: Wow, I was able to mess with it and get a result, not the one I wanted, but it's a start. I've never touched this file, nor do I know javascript. Does this them write inline styles to the global.js file on it's own? if so, that's diabolical.

Comment: apparently, this function dynamically adjusts the margin-bottom of those elements and thereby the overall height of the header (resulting in a "vertical symmetry")

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML I notice it's rendered with an error `style="margin-bottom: 73px;"`, instead of `style="margin-bottom: 73px"`. Unless you manually entered this with the error, try searching your entire project folder using an IDE or a code editor to find and replace the string 'style="margin-bottom: 73px;" '.

If you find nothing then you'll have to adjust your search to include what that PHP code might look like. ie `...style="<?php echo 'margin-bottom: 73px;' ?>">`